# Best gesture recognition algorithm for Kinect

Tags: c#, algorithm, kinect, gesture

What are the best methods for gesture recognition on Kinect?

I want to implement:

- hand gestures recognition (palm + whole hands - swipes, waving etc.)
- body state recognition (like jumping, bowing left/right)
- facial gestures recognition (facial tracking is now included in the new Microsoft's libraries for Kinect)

I need to use some algorithms for my work to do this (own implementation :S).
Could anyone help to classify the algorithms for those 3 groups of gestures?

I have to use MS libs from kinectforwindows.com

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you become a Kinect developer?

Comment: Medical data management in Poland:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download from 
[Gesture Detection Using Machine Learning](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=28066)

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about developing your own gesture recognition algorithms, but if you for some reason want to avoid Microsoft's libraries you can try checking out the OpenKinect project and the Openni libraries. You can read more about it here: http://openkinect.org/wiki/Main_Page

If this is still not what you want, the project along with all its documentation will provide you a good basis to begin from.

Comment: Thx, but I rly need to use Microsoft's libraries. Btw. it doesn't mean which one I use, because they both ensure skeletal tracking support. I need to use some algorithms to classify the skeletal/depth data as recognized gestures.

Comment: @Nickon: Cool, maybe just clarify that you want to use the MS libraries, cause currently it's unclear that you want to use that and not just write your own.

Comment: I'm sorry. it's my bad. I have to use Microsoft libs